# U.S.V.A. health coverage outside of CONUS?

Tags: health-care

I have been getting much of my health care from the U.S. Veteran's Administration (VA).  They tell me that they will pay for services if I am more than forty miles (68 KM) from a VA facility.  (I suspect that only applies within USA.)  I do know they cover emergencies anywhere.

Is anyone non-disabled getting non-emergency healthcare paid for by VA outside of U.S. territory?  What is covered and what is "on your own"?

Please don't waste bandwidth telling me VA care is sub-standard.  I already know.  I'm just trying to figure out how much insurance to buy before I go to Spain.

UPDATE: To my surprise, someone from the VA not only responded, but responded after midnight!  Unfortunately, all they gave me was a URI for a page about care for service-connected disabilities.  I was able to find in Code of Federal Regulations (CFR) that the V.A. "may contract with" other providers.  Don't know whether that means they make a deal with a local provider as needed for a specific veteran or whether they only pay for care by providers they made deals with for general service in some area.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [**Veterans Administration, regarding benefits for veterans living abroad**](http://www.benefits.va.gov/persona/veteran-abroad.asp):

> Reimbursed medical care for U.S. Veterans residing or traveling in Canada and other foreign countries is limited to treatment for VA rated service-connected disabilities only.
>
> The Foreign Medical Program (FMP) Office is responsible for determining eligibility for reimbursed medical treatment while traveling or residing abroad, except in the Philippines. Generally, as long as the service is medically necessary for the treatment of a VA rated service-connected condition, it will be covered.
>
> **[Foreign Medical Program (FMP)](https://www.va.gov/purchasedcare/programs/veterans/fmp/)**
>
> The Foreign Medical Program (FMP) is a U.S. Department of Veterans Affairs (VA) health care benefits program for U.S. Veterans who are residing or traveling abroad and have VA-rated, service-connected disabilities. Under FMP, VA assumes payment responsibility for certain necessary health care services received in foreign countries and associated with the treatment of service-connected disabilities, or any disability associated with and held to be aggravating a service-connected condition. Additionally, VA may authorize necessary foreign medical services for any condition for a veteran participating in the VA Vocational Rehabilitation Program.

Comment: I'm not eligible for FMP, and even though I make it plain in every VA inquiry that I am not and WHY I am not, the response nevertheless always tells me how I can sign up for the FMP and never answers the question I actually asked.  Just like here where I specifically used the term NON-disabled.